# Adding custom properties to "Server response time" aggregated metric

Tags: azure-application-insights

"Server response time" metric is pushed to ApplicationInsights and to Geneva (using 1DS SDK)

I see the metric is pre-aggregated by AI modules and has a set of default properties attached to it according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported)

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.microsoft.com/questions/37878) that it is possible to add properties to RequestTrackingtelemetry and other telemetry events.
Is it possible to attach custom properties to "Server response time" metric(it being an aggregated metric)?

It is an ASP.NET MVC application built on .NET framework.

**Telemetry Initializer registration**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    
    /* Some code here */
    
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =
        ConfigManagerProvider.GetValueFromConfigFile(ConfigManagerConstants.AppInsightsInstrumentationKey);

    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new TelemetryInitializer());

    /* Some code here */
}
```

**TelemetryInitializer class:**

```
public class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry == null){
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(telemetry));
            }
            telemetry.Context.Component.Version = MvcApplication.Version;

            //Suggested code
            MetricTelemetry metricTelemtry = telemetry as MetricTelemetry;
            if (metricTelemtry != null){
                metricTelemtry.Properties["Test"] = "dummyValue";
            } // end of Suggested code

            switch (telemetry)
            {
                case RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry:
                {
                    AddTlsLoggingTelemetry(requestTelemetry);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddTlsLoggingTelemetry(RequestTelemetry telemetry)
        {
           /* Some custom properties addition */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I did some additional digging and this is possible, but it's not straightforward. This involves [using custom metrics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/), so there are cost implications of using it.

Essentially what is going on is that there are actually two different data stores involved. There's the main log store which includes custom properties and the aggregated metric store which strips off any custom properties. In order to preserve them we need to leverage custom metrics.

In short, by making a copy of the "Server response time" metric and removing the "_MS.IsAutocollected" and "_MS.MetricId" properties from the copy we keep all the collected data but the copy is treated as a custom metric. This also preserves the original standard metric so it won't break anything that relies on it. Since you are already using a switch statement to add properties to just request telemetry, I added the metric telemetry to that. I didn't have any issues reading the response time property in the initializer, but any custom properties are stripped from the standard metric when it is stored.

```
switch (telemetry)
{
    case RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry:
        {
            AddTlsLoggingTelemetry(requestTelemetry);
            break;
        }
    case MetricTelemetry metricTelemetry:
        {
            if (metricTelemetry.Name == "Server response time" 
                && metricTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("_MS.IsAutocollected")) {
                var client = new TelemetryClient();
                var metricCopy = metricTelemetry.DeepClone() as MetricTelemetry;
                metricCopy.Context.GlobalProperties.Remove("_MS.IsAutocollected");
                metricCopy.Context.GlobalProperties.Remove("_MS.MetricId");
                metricCopy.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("foo", "bar");
                client.TrackMetric(metricCopy);
            }

            break;
        }
}
```

*One note: I did try modifying the name property in the copy but it still showed up in App Insights as "Server response time". It shows in a different namespace in the metrics view so it is possible to tell them apart.*

Once the new metric starts sending data, it comes up in the log view with the custom property set in the initializer in the customMetrics table.

[image]

In the metrics view, the customized response time metric is available under the azure.applicationinsights namespace.

[image]

If you want to use your custom properties in the metrics view as there are [additional costs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pre-aggregated-metrics-log-metrics#custom-metrics-dimensions-and-pre-aggregation) for this. If you enable this feature you'll be able to use your custom property for filtering and splitting your data in the metrics view.

[image: From docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pre-aggregated-metrics-log-metrics#custom-metrics-dimensions-and-pre-aggregation]

**Original Answer**

Every table currently in the Application Insights data model has a customDimensions property you can use to store additional information about an item and that includes aggregated metrics.

[TelemetryProcessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#itelemetryprocessor-and-itelemetryinitializer) allow you to modify the contents of App Insights messages, including those automatically generated by the SDK. Checking to see if an item is a MetricTelemetry item should let you modify just the metrics, and you could filter further by name to find the one you want.

```
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var metricTelemetry = telemetry as MetricTelemetry;
        // Is this a Metric ?
        if (metricTelemetry == null) return;
        metricTelemetry.Properties["CustomProperty"] = "custom data"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried this, but the control doesn't flow into the Initialize method for processing this specific metric.

Comment: Interesting. As far as I'm aware all metrics are supposed to flow through that system. A couple of follow up questions for you to see if I can repro the issue. Are you in .NET Framework or .NET Core? Also, could you share the code you were using as a telemetry initializer and the code you used to register the custom initializer.

Comment: For the lack of space in comment, editing the original question with the details.

Comment: @Kavya I've updated the answer with additional information about how to make this work. It isn't possible in the standard metrics, so I needed to use a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @SamaraSoucy-MSFT for investing time into this. I am confused about this, if control isn't flowing into the Initialize method for this specific metric, how does adding code to create custom metric work? Am I missing something obvious? Could you please help sharing your ApplicationInsights.config file? I can ping you offline.

Comment: I didn't have any trouble getting the metric in the initializer. It only fires once a minute so I did have to navigate to at least one page and then wait. I uploaded the code including the appinsights.config to Github for you: https://github.com/SamaraSoucy-MSFT/appinsights-custom-server-response-time If you need a way to contact me offline, you can send an email to azcommunity(at)microsoft.com with a link to this thread.